# ¿Cómo extraer de un txt, solo las filas que tengan un número en común en sus columnas?

Tags: php, txt

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo un menú con los meses del año, y al hacer clic sobre el mes se envía por GET el número del mes.

**Menú:**

```
<a href='cpae2.php?m=1'><div class="btn1">Enero</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=2'><div class="btn1">Febrero</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=3'><div class="btn1">Marzo</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=4'><div class="btn1">Abril</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=5'><div class="btn1">Mayo</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=6'><div class="btn1">Junio</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=7'><div class="btn1">Julio</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=8'><div class="btn1">Agosto</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=9'><div class="btn1">Septiembre</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=10'><div class="btn1">Octubre</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=11'><div class="btn1">Noviembre</div></a>
    <a href='cpae2.php?m=12'><div class="btn1">Diciembre</div></a>
```

Luego tengo un TXT con filas y columnas (como se muestra en el ejemplo) y en la primer columna de cada fila, está el número del mes. En este ejemplo, el número 2, que corresponde a febrero.

**TXT:**

**2;11;febrero;11:00;Maipú;Metropolitana**
6;15;junio;11:00;San Pedro;Metropolitana
**2;8;febrero;11:00;Huechuraba;Metropolitana**
6;10;junio;11:00;Peñalolén;Metropolitana;Suspendida
3;16;marzo;11:00;María Pinto;Metropolitana;Suspendida
**2;22;febrero;11:00;Paine;Metropolitana;Suspendida**
9;28;septiembre;11:00;Talagante;Metropolitana

**Acá mi problema:** Cuando el usuario selecciona un mes (febrero en este caso), debería mostrar todas las filas en las cuales aparezca el número 2 en sus columnas. Según mi TXT, debería mostrar tres filas. Por otro lado, sería ideal no imprimir la primer columna, ya solo es el número del mes que seleccionó.

**Este es mi script:**

```
if(isset($_GET["m"])){

$m = $_GET["m"];

$handle = fopen("cpae.csv", "r");
$todo = fread($handle, filesize("cpae.csv"));


$lineas = explode(chr(13).chr(10), $todo);

    
    $bandera = 0;

   echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>N° MES</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>DÍA</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>MES</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>HORA</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>COMUNA</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>REGIÓN</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>OBSERVACIONES</td>
        </tr>";


    for($i=0; $i<count($lineas); $i++){

       $palabras = explode(";", $lineas[$i]);

        if($m == $palabras[0]){

            //echo "el numero es ".$m;
            
            //echo'<td>'.$r.'</td>';

                foreach ( $palabras as $r ) {
                                                  

                                    echo'<td>'.$r .'</td>';
                                                     
                       
                            }

                echo "</tr></table>";

            $bandera = 1;

            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hay un if de mas adentro del segundo foreach no?

Comment: Si, olvidé quitarlo, solo estaba probando.

Comment: pues quietalo... pone el codigo real que tenes...

Comment: ahí lo saque. No sé como hacer para que imprima todas las filas que tengan el 2 al inicio de sus columnas.

Comment: echo "</tr></table>"; esta mal ubicado..deberias ponerlo despues de recorrer todo el archivo, no la primera fila...

Comment: Claro, puede ser, aún así, no es ese el motivo por el cual no imprime

Comment: Y donde abrias las filas?

Comment: del archivo TXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y si pruebas con una función que te devuelva el HTML de la table, algo como esto:

```php
function generarTabla($numero, $rutaArchivo) {
  $tablaHtml = "<table>
                <tr>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>N° MES</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>DÍA</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>MES</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>HORA</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>COMUNA</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>REGIÓN</td>
                <td class='tdTitulo'>OBSERVACIONES</td>
                </tr>";

  $archivo = fopen($rutaArchivo, "r");

  if ($archivo) {
    while (($linea = fgets($archivo)) !== false) {
      $campos = explode(";", $linea);

      if ($campos[0] == $numero) {
        $tablaHtml .= "<tr>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[1] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[2] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[3] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[4] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[5] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . $campos[6] . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . (isset($campos[7]) ? $campos[7] : "") . "</td>";
        $tablaHtml .= "</tr>";
      }
    }

    fclose($archivo);
  }

  $tablaHtml .= "</table>";

  return $tablaHtml;
}
```

Y para llamarla:

```php
$numero = $_GET["m"];
$rutaArchivo = "cpae.csv";
$tabla=generarTabla($numero,$rutaArchivo);
echo $tabla;
```

Ya comentaras

Comment: Maravillo!, era lo que necesitaba. No sabes cuan agradecido. Hay una línea que no supe cuál es su función: $tablaHtml .= "<td>" . (isset($campos[7]) ? $campos[7] : "") . "</td>";

Comment: Es para que no tire error al no conseguir la delimitación de **observación** ya que no todas las líneas veo la tienen. _No olvides tildar la respuesta como satisfactoria_

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias Jefferson.